# Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda?

Tags: angular

I get an error when try to start npm:

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda
```

with a reference to an exported function (position 47:19 
in the original .ts file), resolving symbol 
CoreModule in D:/Projects/UI3/src/app/core/core.module.ts

**Core is:**

```
providers: [
    {provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => { // Here 47 line number
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]},
    AuthenticationService,
    DialogsService,
    AuthenticationGuard,
    I18nService
  ]
```

So, it had worked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract your arrow function like:

```typescript
export function httpServiceFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) { 
    return new HttpService(backend, options);
}

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
        provide: HttpService,
        useFactory: httpServiceFactory,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    AuthenticationService,
    DialogsService,
    AuthenticationGuard,
    I18nService
  ]
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262

Comment: Thanks! You are a hero!